# Loading images dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scenario where I have a user select an image to upload to his/her user profile on my webpage. I'm using .net's MVC3 architecture for my website. What i need is for the image to show on the page after he chooses the one he wants but before i store it in the database. I searched around and ended up trying this which a friend of mine said worked for him:

In the view I tried:

```
<div class="floatRight">
    <a onclick="opendialogbox('imageLoad2');" style="cursor: pointer">Photo</a>
    <img src="… " width="16" height="16" id="imgThumbnail2" alt="photo" />
    <input type="file" name="imageLoad2" accept="image/*" id="imageLoad2" onchange="ChangeImage('imageLoad2','#imgThumbnail2')" hidden="hidden" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function opendialogbox(inputid) {
        document.getElementById(inputid).click();
    }

function ChangeImage(fileId, imageId) {
        var ext = document.getElementById(fileId).value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'bmp':
            case 'png':
            case 'gif':
            case 'jpeg':
                {
                    var myform = document.createElement("form");
                    myform.style.display = "none";
                    myform.action = "/ImagePreview/AjaxSubmit";
                    myform.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
                    myform.method = "post";
                    var imageLoad;
                    var imageLoadParent;
                    //test browser used then submit form
                    $(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success:
                        function (responseText) {
                            var d = new Date();
                            $(imageId)[0].src = "/ImagePreview/ImageLoad?a=" + d.getMilliseconds();
                            if (document.all || is_chrome)//IE
                                imageLoadParent.appendChild(myform.firstChild);
                            else//FF                     
                                document.body.removeChild(myform);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert('Error, please select an image.');
        }

    }

</script>
```

And in the controller i tried:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AjaxSubmit(int? id)
        {
            Session["ContentLength"] = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
            Session["ContentType"] = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
            byte[] b = new byte[Request.Files[0].ContentLength];
            Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(b, 0, Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            Session["ContentStream"] = b;
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
            string myFilePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/Auxiliar.png"));
            file.SaveAs(myFilePath);
            return Content(Request.Files[0].ContentType + ";" + Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
        }



        public ActionResult ImageLoad(int? id)
        {
            byte[] b = (byte[])Session["ContentStream"];
            int length = (int)Session["ContentLength"];
            string type = (string)Session["ContentType"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = type;
            Response.BinaryWrite(b);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            Session["ContentLength"] = null;
            Session["ContentType"] = null;
            Session["ContentStream"] = null;
            return Content("");
        }
```

now all this i thought made sense but when i try it in my website the method never reaches the server (I placed a break-point at the beginning of both methods in the controller). I also used firefox's firebug to trace the script on the page until it reaches the line:

```
$(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success:
                        function (responseText) {
                            var d = new Date();
                            $(imageId)[0].src = "/ImagePreview/ImageLoad?a=" + d.getMilliseconds();
                            if (document.all || is_chrome)//IE
                                imageLoadParent.appendChild(myform.firstChild);
                            else//FF                     
                                document.body.removeChild(myform);
                        }
                    });
```

here it continues but never enters the success condition. I thought it might be a problem with the JQuery versions included on the page and noticed that my friends site included: jquery-1.5.1.min.js, jquery-1.3.2.js and jquery_form.js

I added these to my website (which was using jquery-1.7.2.min.js) but the problem continued. Not sure if including various versions of jquery would cause some kind of conflict with the methods or if the problem is somewhere else.

I would greatly appreciate any help on the matter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Donnie, it's still hard to deduce what the problem is here, but there are some things you can do to identify the exact nature of the problem.

First, you're handling the success condition, but you'll also want to handle error conditions with a similar anon function like your wrote above.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ has some info on this, but essentially you're going to write:

```
$(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success: function (responseText) {
                                  // your success method
                                },
                       error: function (responseText) {
                                  // your error method
                                }
                });
```

Next, FireBug is great, but you'll also want to use it's network monitoring capabilities, not just the script debugger.  Chances are there is a very relevant 500 or 404 coming back there that you're not aware of.

If it is a 404, it might be related to this line:

```
myform.action = "/ImagePreview/AjaxSubmit";
```

I usually new up a var and let MVC build my action url like so:

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'
```

As a best practice I'll usually inject this URL as part of my view model, or store it in the view in a hidden field, but this is also okay.

Hope these tips help some.  Cheers.

Comment: First of thanks for your time. The link you sent helped me realizae one thing... the $(myform).ajaxsubmit() method is not part of the jquery library.... its actually part of the jquery_forms plugin. Am looking into this now. thanks again